# Simple Jquery True and false issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

what's different between the codes below...

```
loop here{

   .....
   .....

   if($element.length == 0){

          return true;
  }
   ....
   ..... 
}


---------------------------------------------

loop here{

 ....
 ....
if($element.length == 0){


          return false;
  } 
 ....
 ....

}
```

not sure what's different between return ture and return false inside a loop. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One makes the value of the surrounding function be `true`, and the other makes it `false` ... it's pretty basic stuff. The code is in a function, and a `return` executed anywhere within the function returns from the function, loop or no loop.

Comment: What pointy said, and both will stop the loop from happening as well.

Comment: If you just want to end the loop but not the function, then use `break`

Comment: They're indented differently and have a different number of periods. Oh, and they return opposite values.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The answer might be, that sometimes returning a specific value from a javascript function can result in canceling a UI behavior or event.

For example if you have an HTML form that has an submit action that executes a javascript function, then if the function returns false, it will cancel the submit.  If the function returned true, then it would allow the submit to complete its full lifecycle.

One place you might want to do this, continuing our example, if is the form submit action did some data validation before sending the data off.  If validation did not pass, it could display a message and then return false, so the user could change their data accordingly, before trying to submit again.

Answer (score 1):

The first one says that if the length of the element is null, return true the other one returns false if so. Now in the loop (just an example) if you were removing letters from an element (bad example? :P ) as soon as it encounters that condition: 
For the first one: 
if the length is null, the returned `true` can mean that the loop has to stop, it will depend of what the loop does. 
For the second one, it's the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looping with the `.each()`?

Then `return true;` will cause the loop to continue, while `return false;` will cause the loop to stop.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/each/